# How to cache random results using Ember data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-components

Thanks to whoever is reading this and helping out. I'm going to describe what's already working, and then where I'm trying to get to (which I can't figure out):

**What's working:**
In an EmberJS Component, there is a button that populates a textbox with a random string from a given collection of EmberData objects. The `model()` function queries for all of the objects from the API, and then the `random_search()` function picks a random one from the list and inserts it into the textbox. The code so far looks like this:

In `componennt.js`:

```
export default Component.extend({
  store: service('store'),
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('randomsearchitem').then(function(items) {
      return items.map(function(item) {
        return {id: item.get('id'), funnnystory: item.get('funnystory')};
      })
    });
  },
  actions: {
    random_search() {
      this.model().then(function(items) {
        $('#searchbar-searchtext').val(items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]['id']);
        $('#searchbar-form').submit();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In `view.hbs`:

```
<button onclick={{action "random_search"}}>I'm Feeling Lucky!</button>
```

**What I want:**
I would like to have:

1. `model()` query for 15 random objects from the API and cache them locally, persisting between page loads. The API will potentially have a list of 1000's of them and I'd like to implement this logic client-side if possible. If this were SQL the query would look something like `SELECT * FROM 'randomsearchitems' LIMIT 15`
2. `random_search()` to select one item, use it, and then discard it from the cache
3. Once all 15 have been used once, I want to call the API again for a new list of 15 strings
4. Uniqueness does not have to be enforced -- if the list of new objects contains an object that was present in the previous list, that's ok

Thankss

Comment: I don’t know enough Ember to give you a true answer, but I’d stick those 15 random search items into a property and have another property called `current_search` that’s a number between 0 and 14. Every button press, increment the number 1 and display the value at that index. When your number = 15, then do another API call reset your counter back to 0. There’s no reason to do any randomized logic on the client side. That’s all handled by the server. Just slowly count up through your random results. Trying to do randomized logic in the client will just make things more confusing for you.

Comment: I would make your random query endpoint a backend thing, rather than implement on the frontend. Is there a particular reason you're wanting to do it on the frontend?

Comment: I'm trying to keep the backend as simple as possible for people reasons, but if it makes more sense to put in the back end I'm good with that. The caching is my primary concern here :)

Comment: Also, if possible, async cache updates would be good; i.e. after 13 out of 15 items have been used, trigger an API call to the backend async to the user, so that if the backend call fails there are still 2 new items in the cache to use. I know this a little overkill for the use case described but I have a few others coming up that I will use the same code for.

Comment: it sounds like by "cache" you just want to have two different lists of these 15 items. One list is ALL of them, the other list is whatever you have 'used'. This could go either on the controller, a service, or in a component, depending usage.

Comment: Technically yes, except the first list of 'available' items can be 1000's of items long, so I don't want to transfer them all to every client that connects. So that list needs to stay on the backend, with a smaller list of 15 in the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't exactly what you are asking for, but I'd have the backend provide the random 15 items, and use the following code.

```
export default Route.extend({
  async model() {
    let response = await fetch('/api/whatever-endpoint');
    let json = await response.json();

    return { items: json };
  }
});
```

then, in a *controller*

```
export default Controller.extend({
  searchText: '',

  actions: {
    didSubmitForm() {
      // do something here on submit
      // fetch again? add item to list?
      // depends!
    }
    search() {
      let items = this.model.items;
      let randomId = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length].id

      $('#searchbar-searchtext').val(randomId);
      $('#searchbar-form').submit(); // or call a native function here
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks :). For anyone else reaching this page, on each use I'm repopulating the list in the `didSubmitForm()` method to bring it back up to 15 items so that it's never empty.